# Настройка версии интерпретатора Python в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm использует системный Python 2.7, хотя у меня выбран Python 3.9. В настройках интерпретатора Python 2.7 удален.

Но почему то PyCharm все равно используется Python 2.7.

Как просто переключиться на установленный Python 3.9, без создания venv?

[image: Справа внизу выбран Python 3.9]

Настройка интерпретатора[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: В командной строке запускайте через python3